# Punya shloko Nalo Raja meaning

Tags: shloka

I read a shloka (source not known)" Punya shloko Nalo Raja Punya shloko Yudhishtirah. Punya shloko Videhascha Punya shloko Janardanah." 
What is meaning of Punyashloka in the above context

Comment: If you're satisfied with the answer below, you can accept it by clicking on the tick mark (✓) below the voting buttons.

Answer (score 4):

Puṇyaśloka (पुण्यश्लोक) means well spoke of good fame or about whom we should remember for his great actions, according to [Sanskrit dictionary](http://sanskritdictionary.com/pu%E1%B9%87ya%C5%9Bloka/136995/1).

> puṇyaśloka पुण्यश्लोक
>
> Definition: mf(ā-)n.   "well spoken of", of good fame or reputation (puṇyaślokeyakarman keya-karman- mfn.one whose actions must be praised in auspicious verses)

This shloka is one of those which are usually recited in morning and grouped as [Pratah Smaranam](https://sa.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A4:%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%A3%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D). This sloka is known as Punyajana Stuti (refer [Stuti Sangraha](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_deities_misc/devadevatAstutisangrahaH.html?lang=sa) ) i.e praise of great personalities.

Here Nalo Raja = Raja [Nala](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nala), [Yudhisthira](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yudhishthira), Videha = King [Janaka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Janaka), Janardana = Lord Krishna are whose great action for preserving Dharma and righteousness can be found and learned from Itihasa and Puranas. So, this shloka is for remembering them.

You can read English meaning of this Shloka from [sanskritdocuments](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_z_misc_misc/prAtahsmaranam.html?lang=sa):

> पुण्यश्लोको नलो राजा पुण्यश्लोको युधिष्ठिरः ।
>   पुण्यश्लोको विदेहश्च पुण्यश्लोको जनार्दनः ॥ १६॥
>
> Meaning:-Raja Nala, the truthful Yudhisthira, Janaka the king of Videha,
>   and Janardana (i. e.) Lord Krishna -the very utterance of these names
>   sanctifies the tongue.